# Python - Push Notification through FCM / APNs to IOS or Android Devices

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on my python project, i need to create my own push notification server for apns and fcm / gcm, which sends push notification to both ios and android at same time, I have looked through the Firebase documentation however, the there was no code examples on the site. Can any one give me an idea of how to complete this in Python code?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for a little while so I thought I will post the code that worked for me eventually. All you need to do is to do a pip install of oauth2client from Google (https://github.com/google/oauth2client):

**pip install oauth2client**

Now, you will need to import the service account which will generate for you a short lived token that you can use in your API so that your app server can communicate with the FCM Google server.

Do as instructed by the following website:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def _get_access_token():
  """Retrieve a valid access token that can be used to authorize requests.

  :return: Access token.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      'service-account.json', FCM_SCOPE)
  access_token_info = credentials.get_access_token()
  return access_token_info.access_token
```

Now, once you have the short_lived token, you can use it in your API calls to send messages to your android / IOS devices:

```
import requests, json
values = {"message":{"token":"<insert android firebase token id here>","notification":{"body":"This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message for testing!","title":"FCM Message!!"}}}
header ={ 'Content-Length': '33333', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; UTF-8', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _get_access_token(), 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<insert project name here>/messages:send'
print(header)
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(values), headers=header)
print(r.text)
```

If the call is successful, you will receive a print on the screen of the reference of your FCM message that you have just sent:

```
{
  "name": "projects/<your project name>/messages/0:1519633952417262%0958967209589672"
}
```